The correct way to present information or instructions
Should I say
"Your clothes should be dry during welding process"?
They say that "should be" gets a past participle after it. So should it be "dried"? Or it's not even "should be" to start with? Maybe it's "must be"?
If the sentence itself was wrong, what is the correct way to say it?

[the welding process], should be dry, should be wet, should be quiet, etc.

Who's "they"? -

There are many correct ways to write any given sentence or idea. Your sentence sounds mostly natural, although it is missing an article. Here are a few ways to say this:

Your clothes should be dry during the welding process.
Ensure your clothes are dry during the welding process.
Your clothes must be dry during the welding process.
The welding process requires dry clothes.
Clothing must be dry during welding.

Dry vs Dried
These actually mean two different things. An item that is dry is not wet. The verb is is to note a state of being. An item that has been dried is an item that was wet and a person or machine or the sun did the work to dry it. The verb is to dry.
If the clothes you are talking about previously were wet and you want to tell the reader that they must dry the clothes before they can weld, I would say that as:

Your clothes should be dried before you begin welding.
Dry your clothes fully before welding.

Here, the preposition before is used instead of during since the verb to dry will happen before the process being talked about. But, if using a state of being verb, those two things will happen at the same time, so during is appropriate.
Should vs Must
In most contexts, should and must mean nearly exactly the same thing. Must is stronger, and clearly states that something is required, not optional. Should means that something is a suggestion or that it is recommended.
In this context (like a manual about welding), it's likely that either could work.
